# Thymeleaf does not use UTF-8 to transmit form data to rest endpoint

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am currently working on a Spring Boot project with Thymeleaf.

Using the following form should send the data to a REST endpoint:

```html
<form th:action="@{/post/create}" method="post" th:object="${postDto}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="title" class="form-label">Titel</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" th:field="*{title}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="content" class="form-label">Beschreibung</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="4" th:field="*{content}" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="event" class="form-label">Event</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="event" name="event" th:field="*{eventId}">
            <option th:value="${0}">Kein Event</option>
            <option th:each="event : ${events}" th:value="${event.id}" th:text="${event.name} + ' - ' + ${event.getClassName()}"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="topic" class="form-label">Thema</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="topic" name="topic" th:field="*{topicId}">
            <option th:value="${0}">Kein Thema</option>
            <option th:each="topic : ${topics}" th:value="${topic.id}" th:text="${topic.name}"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="visibility" class="form-label">Sichtbarkeit</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="visibility" name="visibility" th:field="*{visibility}">
            <option th:value="${0}">Für alle sichtbar</option>
            <option th:each="role : ${roles}" th:value="${role.getVisibilityScore()}" th:text="${role.getVisibilityScore()} + ' - ' + ${role.name}"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Absenden</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The REST-Endpoint is receiving the data and should create a Post object in the ServiceImpl:

```java
@PostMapping("/post/create")
    public String createPost(@ModelAttribute @Valid PostDto postDto,
                             BindingResult bindingResult,
                             Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute(ERROR_MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTE, "Es gab Probleme, den Beitrag anzulegen. Versuche es erneut.");
            return TEMPLATE_LOCATION;
        }
        try {
            postService.savePost(postDto);
            model.addAttribute(SUCCESS_MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTE, "Beitrag wurde erstellt!");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            model.addAttribute(ERROR_MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTE, e.getMessage());
        }
        return TEMPLATE_LOCATION;
    }
```

PostDto:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PostDto {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String title;

    @Lob
    @Column(length = 100000)
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String content;

    private Long eventId;

    private Long topicId;

    @Min(0)
    @Max(100)
    @NotNull
    private Long visibility;
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```java
@Override
    public void savePost(PostDto postDto) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findByMailAddress(authentication.getName());

        if (!permissionService.canCreatePosts(user)) {
            throw new InsufficientPermissionsException(INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS_EXCEPTION);
        }

        Post post = Post.builder()
                .title(postDto.getTitle())
                .content(postDto.getContent())
                .visibility(postDto.getVisibility())
                .event(eventService.getById(postDto.getEventId()))
                .topic(topicService.getById(postDto.getTopicId()))
                .creator(user)
                .creationDate(LocalDateTime.now())
                .build();

        postRepository.save(post);
        topicService.mailToSubscribers(post.getTopic());
    }
```

Using the Spring Data JPA the object should get persisted in a database and users can read the post on the site.

After submitting the form, i logged the PostDto object and its already messed up and character like "ä", "ö", "ü" or other will be replaced with a "?".

I tried setting the following settings in the `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.enabled=true
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
```

I found no solution in the web and used ChatGPT but got no awnser that fixed my problem.

Comment: What are you seeing which makes you think you have this problem? And where are you seeing the problem? Can you show us the evidence and the context in which it is displayed? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: In case it is relevant: Thymeleaf is not responsible for transmitting form data. It is responsible for rendering HTML content. Do you see the same problem if you hard-code your HTML (no use of Thymeleaf)?

Comment: Thank you for the updates. But... (a) "_Can you show us the evidence_" - I was trying to suggest you show us precisely how and where you are seeing these question marks.  But all I see is "_i logged the PostDto object_". How did you log it? To where? And how did you view the results? I'm not saying this is the problem, but what if you are viewing a log file using a viewer where the font does not support accented characters? OK - that is unlikely, but I hope that makes my point. (b) "_Thymeleaf is not responsible_" - so, what happens if you create a [mre] which does not even use Thymeleaf?

Comment: (c) It could be something completely different - for example, maybe `application.properties` is in the wrong location. Again, this is probably not the problem, but it's hard to know one way or the other. See [mre]. Or someone else may be able to help based on the new info you have provided.